# Flashing Jetson TX2 but NVIDIA SDK Manager cannot avoid fail

Tags: sdk, nvidia, nvidia-jetpack-sdk

I was trying

- jetpack 3.3.4 , ubuntu 18.04
- jetpack 4.5.1 , ubuntu 18.04
- jetpack 4.6.1 , ubuntu 18.04
- jetpack 4.6.2 , ubuntu 18.04
- jetpack 4.6.3 , ubuntu 18.04

I studied that this process is easily fail so I thought using different version jetpack to try, well , those are fail too, I have no idea how to move on. Therefore, asking in here
[image]

this is the `SDKM_logs_JetPack_4.5.1`
I put the online share zip file link here https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202212165hJEIyxY

please take a look, and if get any suggestion just let me know

Comment: Could you include the error messages in your post?

Comment: I zip the error message and share the online  [link](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202212165hJEIyxY) here

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues for using new versions of Ubuntu like 20 and higher. Consider using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).